# Gradient fill and color transition in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

[image: Image example]

In the example figure, I have two uncoloured regions. I would like to plot a smooth color transition when transitioning across the two regions. For example, I would like to start off with yellow on the left-most part of the uncoloured region, then slowly transition to orange, with the strongest orange intensity on the rightmost part of the figure.

Is there any way this can be done? I'm not sure if this can be done with fill_between.

```
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
matplotlib.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = "Arial"
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = "sans-serif"

#points for the three lines
x_1=[0.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00,6.00,6.50]
y_1=[3.00,2.80,2.40,2.20,1.80,1.00,0.20,0.00]

x_2 = [0.00,1.00,2.00,2.80]
y_2 = [7.00,8.00,9.00,10.00]

x_3=[2.80,2.80,3.00,4.00]
y_3=[10.00,6.00,4.00,1.80]

#create comparison arrays for fill_between
y_1_compare=[]
for item in x_1:
    y_1_compare.append(0)

y_2_compare=[]
for item in x_2:
    y_2_compare.append(10)

f=plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax=plt.gca()
plt.plot(x_1,y_1,'o',linestyle='-', color='k',linewidth=0.7)
plt.plot(x_2,y_2,'s',linestyle='-',color='k',linewidth=0.7)
plt.plot(x_3,y_3,'^',linestyle='--',color='k',linewidth=0.7)
ax.set_xlim(0,8)
ax.set_ylim(0,10)
ax.fill_between(x_1, y_1, y_1_compare, where=y_1 >= y_1_compare, facecolor='tab:cyan', interpolate=True,alpha=0.6)
ax.fill_between(x_2, y_2, y_2_compare, where=y_2 <= y_2_compare, facecolor='green', interpolate=True,alpha=0.4)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=15)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The usual way would be to utilise `imshow` for this task. You could of course create a patch in the size of your area and fill it with a gradient colour. Or you just plot first the gradient, and then all of your elements:

```
import matplotlib
from matplotlib import cm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
matplotlib.rcParams['font.sans-serif'] = "Arial"
matplotlib.rcParams['font.family'] = "sans-serif"

#points for the three lines
x_1=[0.00,1.00,2.00,3.00,4.00,5.00,6.00,6.50]
y_1=[3.00,2.80,2.40,2.20,1.80,1.00,0.20,0.00]

x_2 = [0.00,1.00,2.00,2.80]
y_2 = [7.00,8.00,9.00,10.00]

x_3=[2.80,2.80,3.00,4.00]
y_3=[10.00,6.00,4.00,1.80]

#create comparison arrays for fill_between
y_1_compare=[]
for item in x_1:
    y_1_compare.append(0)

y_2_compare=[]
for item in x_2:
    y_2_compare.append(10)

f=plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
ax=plt.gca()
#define size of the graph
xl = 0
xh = 8
yl = 0
yh = 10
#array for gradient creation
arr = [[0, 1], [0, 1]]

#plot a gradient picture first in the desired size, which will also autoscale the graph
#set interpolation to "nearest" to see the underlying grid structure
im1 = plt.imshow(arr,  cmap = cm.Oranges, extent = [xl, xh, yl, yh], interpolation = "bicubic", alpha = .6, aspect = "auto")

plt.plot(x_1,y_1,'o',linestyle='-', color='k',linewidth=0.7)
plt.plot(x_2,y_2,'s',linestyle='-',color='k',linewidth=0.7)
plt.plot(x_3,y_3,'^',linestyle='--',color='k',linewidth=0.7)

#fill the areas with white, so we won't see the underlying picture, when we plot a colour with a reduced alpha
ax.fill_between(x_1, y_1, y_1_compare, where=y_1 >= y_1_compare, facecolor='white', interpolate=True,alpha=1)
ax.fill_between(x_2, y_2, y_2_compare, where=y_2 <= y_2_compare, facecolor='white', interpolate=True,alpha=1)
#now plot again color with reduced alpha
ax.fill_between(x_1, y_1, y_1_compare, where=y_1 >= y_1_compare, facecolor='tab:cyan', interpolate=True,alpha=.4)
ax.fill_between(x_2, y_2, y_2_compare, where=y_2 <= y_2_compare, facecolor='green', interpolate=True,alpha=.6)
ax.tick_params(labelsize=15)
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

There are plenty of [predefined colormaps](https://matplotlib.org/examples/color/colormaps_reference.html), which will keep you busy for some time. And the list `[[0, 1], [0, 1]]` can be of course any kind of array, not just a rough 2 x 2 grid. Try for instance:

```
sp = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)
spy = np.tile(sp, 3)
arr = sp[:, None] * spy[None, :]
```

Comment: Thank you! This pretty much does what I wanted. Any idea why the aspect ratio of the figure is changed? I set the figsize to be a square (5,5) but it is now more of a rectangle. Fiddling with figsize doesn't seem to work.

Comment: `imshow` has an aspect parameter. Standard is obviously that both axis are presented equally. I changed this behaviour now, by setting it explicitly to `auto`, so the picture matches the pre-defined axes

Comment: Adding aspect='auto', then changing extent to be equal dimensions seems to do the trick.

Comment: Did not realise you replied. Yes, what you said is right. Thank you!